# How to move placeholder to top on focus AND while typing?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want the placeholder to move to the top when the textbox is on focus and also while the user is typing.

I'm not sure if this is just html/css or any javascript too.

My current css looks like this, and I have no js code yet:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: .75em;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px; 
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="password"]:focus {
    height: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}

input[type="text"], input[type="password"] {
    height: 50px;
    transition: 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

It almost does the work but the placeholder disappears when I start typing. I'm using twitter-bootstrap, if that makes anything easier!

Thanks.

Comment: If you just inspect that page you'll see that it's not a placeholder that they're manipulating it's a DIV that is floating on top of the INPUT. You should be able to replicate what's happening just by looking at the code on that site.

Comment: Couldn't see any placeholder code, and I was so fixated on that I didn't know they were using another div. So there's no way of making placeholder stay while typing?

Comment: Google's Material Design Lite uses a similar behaviour. [Here](http://codepen.io/joshadamous/pen/yyyqJZ) is an example of how to implement such a feature with HTML/CSS/jQuery. I think you will somehow need JS in general to make it work fine all around.

Comment: The linked page doesn't use JS. It's not needed. You can use the `pointer-events` property and the `:focus` selector to work your way around it with just CSS.

Comment: @BivoKasaju the provided link doesnt work any more, consider changing it or modifying the question

Comment: this is also good example on the same matter https://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-floating-label-pattern-bootstrap/

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You could do it like this

**HTML:**

```
<div>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" />
  <span class="floating-label">Your email address</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
input:focus ~ .floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label{
  top: 8px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
```

Working JSFiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/273ntk5s/2/

Comment: For some reason my floating label is appearing below the text box. Maybe bootstrap is messing up with my code.

Comment: You could change the `top:18px` in `.floating-label` according to your dom setup. So that the floating-label sits within the input.

Comment: I figured a way around, gave position absolute to floating label, and a z-index of >1 because it was hiding behind the text box! It's working, thanks @DivakarDaas

Comment: Cool. Good for you. Happy coding :)

Comment: @DivakarDaas oops minor issue! The text goes back to it's original "placeholder" form after the user has typed and the box is out of focus, so two texts kinda overlap!
Need to figure out a way to keep the "placeholder" small at the top while the box contains text. I think that's javascript?

Comment: @BivoKasaju You could do it with css by just adding this `input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label`. See my updated answer and JSFiddle.

Comment: @DivakarDaas Super Awesome!! Thanks mucho! No idea what :not :valid does, but I'm super happy that it works! :)

Comment: `:not(:focus)` will check if the input element is not focused and `:valid` checks if the input value is valid or not. Note: The `:valid` works when you add `required` to your html input tag.

Comment: Maybe I'm late to the party, but above solution works, except when the input contains `type="email"`. When you tab outside this field, the floating label will grow again to it's former size. Anyone have a workaround / solution for this?

Comment: It's not working with two textboxes, Any other help?

Comment: I think the answer is not complete, floating-label position is absolute and moved relative to page

Answer (score 29):

```css
.user-input-wrp {
 position: relative;
 width: 50%;
}
.user-input-wrp .inputText{
 width: 100%;
 outline: none;
 border:none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
.user-input-wrp .inputText:focus{
 border-color: blue;
 border-width: medium medium 2px;
}
.user-input-wrp .floating-label {
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
 top: 18px;
 left: 10px;
 transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
.user-input-wrp input:focus ~ .floating-label,
.user-input-wrp input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label{
 top: 0px;
 left: 10px;
 font-size: 13px;
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h1>The floating label</h1>
<div class="user-input-wrp">
  <br/>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" required/>
  <span class="floating-label">Your email address</span>
</div>
```

Modified the code from @user1846747 a little.

Comment: If `required` is not used, we need to add little js in the `input` element, with minor css change. Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/v14whx2b/

Comment: Any idea why this breaks if the `pattern` property is set?

Answer (score 12):

**Only using HTML and css**

```css
.searchformfld{
    position: relative;
    margin: 5px 0px;
}
.searchformfld label{
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 10px;
    top:15px;
    cursor: text;

}
.searchformfld input:focus + label,.searchformfld input:not(:placeholder-shown) + label{
    opacity:1;
    transform: scale(.9) translateY(-100%) translateX(-10px);
    color:#000;
}
.searchformfld input:focus{
    border:1px solid #000;
    outline-color: #000;
}
.searchformfld{
    padding: 15px;
    margin:15px 0px;
}
.searchformfld input{
    width:100%;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.searchformfld label,.searchformfld input{
    transition: all 0.2s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
    opacity:0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchformfld">
            <input type="text" class="candidateName" id="candidateName" name="candidateName" placeholder=" "/>
            <label for="candidateName">Candidate name</label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can try the below code. It only uses HTML and CSS and does not reply on Javascript or component libraries:

```css
.text-field {
        position: relative;
        margin: 10px 2.5px 20px 2.5px;
    }

input {
        display: inline-block;
        border: thin solid #fafafa;
        border-bottom: solid medium #999;
        color: #444;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }

    input:focus {
            border: thin solid #32cd32;
            border-bottom: solid medium #32cd32;
            background-color:#fff;
        }

label {
        color: #999;
        position: absolute;
        pointer-events: none;
        left: 10px;
        top: 10px;
        transition: 0.2s;
    }

input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label {
        top: -10px;
        left: 15px;
        font-size: small;
        color: #32cd32;
        background-color:#fff;
        padding:0 5px 0 5px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="text-field">
                <input type="text" required>
                <label>Input field 1</label>
            </div>

            <div class="text-field">
                <input type="text" required>
                <label>Input field 2</label>
            </div>
```

Comment: Any idea why this code breaks when the input element has the `pattern` property set?

Comment: This code indeed does not require JS but you would need to add the required attr....

Answer (score 5):

```css
span{
  display:block;
  }
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder { color:transparent; }
input:focus:-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 4-18 */
input:focus::-moz-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* FF 19+ */
input:focus:-ms-input-placeholder { color:transparent; } /* IE 10+ */
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').focus(function(){
    placeholder = $(this).attr('placeholder');
    if(placeholder != undefined){
      $(this).parent().prepend('<span class="input-placeholder">'+placeholder+'</span>');
    }
  });
  $('input').blur(function(){
    $(this).parent().find('.input-placeholder').remove();
  });
});
</script>
<div>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" placeholder="Email adress" required/>
</div>
```

Comment: ✔ This is the Cleanest way , It also works on your existing website & you dont have  to add floating span manually to each input on whole website. !!

Comment: @THENETSPIDER clean?
It moves the input field to another position where I initially would not expect it to be. On a whole page all contents underneath will be lowered then. I do not think that this is what people want nor expect.

Comment: @DirkSchumacher .. ohh You may be just copying and pasting the code as it is . You must also apply some css, position & animation etc... this code is not for plain html... You may try above css codes too

Answer (score 5):

The solution I want to propose deals with an input with the movement of the placeholder **without the need for the required** attribute

```css
.inputField {
  position: relative;
}

.inputField input {
  padding: 8px 20px;
  padding-top: 18px;
  border: 1.8px solid rgba(107, 107, 107, 0.4);
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 50%;
  color: black;
}

.inputField input:focus {
  border: 1.8px solid #6b6b6b;
  outline: none;
}

.inputField span {
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  padding-left: 20px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: text;
}

.inputField input:focus+span,
.inputField input:not(:placeholder-shown)+span {
  top: 7px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.7) translateY(-10%) translateX(-8.5px);
  transform: scale(0.7) translateY(-10%) translateX(-8.5px);
}

.inputField input,
.inputField span {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="inputField">
  <input type="text" placeholder=" " />
  <span>Placeholder</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great, but have you noticed that if you click on the <span>Placeholder</span> it doesn't open the input? This is not necessary, but do you know a way to get this to work as well?

Comment: Thank you for reporting this issue to me.
I solved the problem by adding a css property to the <span> tag: `pointer-events: none;`

Answer (score 4):

That site isn't moving the placeholder, but placing a div (`.floating-label`) over the input, so when the input is focused the div just animates to be over the input. The key part here is using `pointer-events: none;` in the floating div, so when you click it the event goes through it to the input box behind it.

Answer (score 3):

if your Floating label is not working when required attribute is removed, try this: using input:not(:placeholder-shown)

```css
input:focus ~ .floating-label,
input:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .floating-label{
  top: 8px;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 20px;
  font-size: 11px;
  opacity: 1;
}

.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 35px;
}

.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 20px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input placeholder="" type="text" class="inputText" />
  <span class="floating-label">Your email address</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all above. This is my version.
1, works for input and textarea.
2, Shows red label (invalid input) only when the label is on the top.

```css
.text-base {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 5px 8px;
  border: 2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 6px;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.text-base:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0074d9;
  outline: 0;
}

.text-field {
  position: relative;
}

.text-field input,
.text-field textarea {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.text-field span {
  color: #aaa;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 10px;
  top: 23px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.text-field input:focus+span,
.text-field input:not(:placeholder-shown)+span,
.text-field textarea:focus+span,
.text-field textarea:not(:placeholder-shown)+span {
  top: 2px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: small;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.text-field input:focus:invalid+span,
.text-field input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid+span,
.text-field textarea:focus:invalid+span,
.text-field textarea:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid+span {
  color: red;
}

.w100p {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.w100p textarea {
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-field w100p">
  <input class="text-base w100p" type="text" required placeholder=" ">
  <span>Name *</span>
</div>
<div class="text-field w100p">
  <input class="text-base w100p" type="email" required placeholder=" ">
  <span>E-Mail *</span>
</div>
<div class="text-field w100p">
  <textarea class="text-base w100p" required placeholder=" "></textarea>
  <span>Nachricht *</span>
</div>
```