# Html5 input placeholder change size and position while entering data

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I found on my bank site that while I am entering information into a input field the initial placeholder changes size to smaller and is pushed to the upper left side of the input field.  I find it very helpful for users to see what questions they are asked while typing it into the field instead of placeholder disappearing altogether.  Any ideas on how to best implement it?

Comment: See [this](https://jsfiddle.net/273ntk5s/2/). Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942247/how-to-move-placeholder-to-top-on-focus-and-while-typing)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for something like this https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/01/08/inspiration-text-input-effects/

it is a new trend for `text` `input` styling

Answer (score 0):

Use the onchange JavaScript event:

The HTML Form:

```
<form id="myForm>
<input type="text" onchange="changeForm(this)" id="text">
</form>
```

The JavaScript function:

```
function changeForm(elm) {
elm[0].setAttribute("style", "height: 50px");
}
```