# Move placeholder above the input on focus

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for css code that move the placeholder text above the input on focus. I found this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942247/how-to-move-placeholder-to-top-on-focus-and-while-typing). This code is perfect but my input tag is wrapped inside `<span>` and for that reason general sibling selector is not working. Any ideas how to edit this css?

```
<div>
  <span class='blocking-span'>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" />
  </span>
  <span class="floating-label">Your email address</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not possible with CSS using your current layout.

Comment: If you show your CSS as well, so we can see how it is suppose to render, we might be able to suggest a solution

Comment: css is on the original link in description.

Comment: Could you move `floating-label` after the input within `blocking-span`?

Comment: What does `blocking-span` class do? ... `display: block`?

Comment: Please replace your `<span class="floating-label">` with a `<label>`: `<input type="text" class="inputText" id="foo"/> <label class="floating-label" for="foo">Your email address</label>

Comment: 1. http://bradfrost.com/blog/post/float-label-pattern/ 2. http://allthingssmitty.com/2016/09/25/accessible-floating-labels/ 3. http://codepen.io/aardrian/pen/MeeZrQ

Comment: I noticed you changed the accepted answer, which is fine, do not though that the `:placeholder-shown` is an experimental technology (meaning it can change its behavior at any time), and still, 1.5 year after this answer were given, only work in less than half of all the existing browsers.

Comment: 2022 :placeholder-shown is now in 95% of browsers https://caniuse.com/css-placeholder-shown

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use the CSS pseudo-selector `:placeholder-shown` in this case to detect when to move a fake placeholder out of the way. See example below:

```css
label {
  margin:20px 0;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
}
  
span {
  padding:10px;
  pointer-events: none;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  transition: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
  opacity:0.5;
}

input {
  padding:10px;
}

input:focus + span, input:not(:placeholder-shown) + span {
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-100%) translateX(-30px);
}

/* For IE Browsers*/
input:focus + span, input:not(:-ms-input-placeholder) + span {
  opacity:1;
  transform: scale(0.75) translateY(-100%) translateX(-30px);
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input placeholder=" ">
  <span>Placeholder Text</span>
</label>
```

Comment: I'd suggest setting the font-size instead of scale(0.75) and translateX(-30px)

Comment: What does input:not(:placeholder-shown) + span  do? I recently recreated this effect without the need to add that line in. It is not clear what it is doing.

As @lynx suggested, font-size is much better solution otherwise the x translates are all off when adding multiple inputs

Answer (score 8):

With the given links CSS etc, simply move the `floating-label` inside the `blocking-span`.

By using `position: relative` on the `div` the `floating-label` will still re-position as if it were outside the `blocking-span`

```css
div {
  position: relative; /*  make label relate to div  */
  padding-top: 10px;  /*  make space for label      */
}
.inputText {
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
}
.floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  left: 15px;
  top: 18px;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
}
input:focus ~ .floating-label,
input:not(:focus):valid ~ .floating-label {
  top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class='blocking-span'>
    <input type="text" class="inputText" required/>
    <span class="floating-label">Your email address</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: what should i do for the textarea? @LGSon

Answer (score 0):

If you change `html` structure then your reference example is work but if you don't want change `html` structure then you need to write little jQuery. You can check this.

```js
$(function(){
  $('.blocking-span input').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).parents('.parents-elm').addClass('foucs-content'); // When focus the input area
  });
  $(document).mouseup(function(e){
  if($(e.target).parents('.blocking-span input').length==0 && !$(e.target).is('.blocking-span input')){
   $('.parents-elm').removeClass('foucs-content');
  }
 });
});
```

```css
div{
  position: relative;
}
.blocking-span{
  display: block;
}
.blocking-span input{
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  height: 80px;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  width: 100%;
}
.floating-label{
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  left: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -webkit-calc(50% - 10px);
  top: -moz-calc(50% - 10px);
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
  transition: top 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
}
.foucs-content .floating-label{
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parents-elm">
  <span class='blocking-span'>
  <input type="text" class="inputText" />
  </span>
  <span class="floating-label">Your email address</span>
</div>
```