# Move label of input box when a user focuses on this without require

Tags: html, css

I want to move a label above an input box when a user focuses on the input box. [There is an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42233488/move-placeholder-above-the-input-on-focus), however, there are some differences. I can't use required as I am using custom validations. Also, there is more than one input box.

See my code below. I must be missing something silly.

```css
.field {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.form label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 10px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input:focus ~ label {
  top: -6px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">

  <div class="field">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text">
  </div>

</form>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To create this with just css you need to change order of `input` and `label` so you can use `+` selector. Then you can use `transform: translate()` on `label` when you focus `input`

```css
form {
  display: inline-block;
}
.field {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
label {
  order: -1;
  padding-left: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  transform: translateY(20px);
  pointer-events: none;
}
input:focus + label {
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
  <div class="field">
    <input type="text">
    <label>Name</label>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <input type="text">
    <label>Age</label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: hey man thanks! its not really working though. Should be the other way around

Comment: nice man! is there anyway to have it so that if the box contains text that I can keep it above? Guess I will need to do that with js as i am not using `required`

Comment: I think you will have to use jquery to detect if input has value or not.

Comment: If you are going to use jquery then you don't need to change order in css or html at all you can just do this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1855/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142898/discussion-between-raul-rodriguez-and-nenad-vracar).