# Cannot able to float label to top when focus in textbox

Tags: html, css

I want to float the label when users focus on textboxes as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942247/how-to-move-placeholder-to-top-on-focus-and-while-typing), but on focus the label does not move upwards. Below is my code.

```css
.input-base-input {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: .5px solid #a9abb3;
    background: transparent;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.input-base-input:focus ~ .input-base-label,
.input-base-input:not(:focus):valid ~ .input-base-label{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    transition-property: top;
    transition-duration: .1s;
}

.input-base-label {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top:-10;
    transition-property: top;
    transition-duration: .1s;
}
```

```html
<label for="pincode" class="input-base-label">Pin Code</label>
<input class="input-base-input" maxlength="6">
```

Comment: Label needs to follow the input according to your css (and the question you were looking at).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this CSS:

```
.input-base-input:focus ~ .input-base-label
```

will select the label which comes after the input (and not before as shown in your code), so first change the order of input and label.

Second, you have not specified the correct value for the `top` property of `.input-base-label`:

```
.input-base-label {
  ...
  /* Not correct */
  top: -10;
  /* Correct */
  top: -10px;
  /* or */
  top: 0;
  ...
}
```

Third, `:valid` selector will make your input valid even if it's empty (so your label will be floated on the page load). To resolve this with CSS-only approach, [add `required` attribute to the `input`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16956610/9180111).

So, your final result might look like this:

```
<input class="input-base-input" id="pincode" name="pincode" maxlength="6" required>
<label class="input-base-label" for="pincode">Pin code</label>
```

```css
.input-base-input {
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: .5px solid #a9abb3;
    background: transparent;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.input-base-label {
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    top: 0;
    transition-property: top;
    transition-duration: .1s;
}

.input-base-input:focus ~ .input-base-label,
.input-base-input:not(:focus):valid ~ .input-base-label {
    display: block;
    top: -10px;

    /* The following properties are not needed as they are specified previously */
    /*
    position: absolute;
    transition-property: top;
    transition-duration: .1s;
    */
}
```

```html
<input class="input-base-input" id="pincode" name="pincode" maxlength="6" required>
<label class="input-base-label" for="pincode">Pin code</label>
```