# increase width and add placeholder to mat input(angular ~5)

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am using mat input(code is below): which looks/appears like this(below screenshot) - add a placholder which disappears once user starts typing.. Currently with my implementation , the text shifts upwards and floats(once the focus is on the input box) and the text keep appearing on the UI.

Can someone assist me in achieving what I want??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `padding`, you don't need to change the `height` of an input. To change the color of the placeholder, use [`::placeholder`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_placeholder.asp). Increasing `font-size` will also increase the height of the input.

```css
input {
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #efefef;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Example Input" />
```

Comment: I am using angular/angular-material ~5 .
Does it have something to do with the version. Reason I am saying this is most of the answers doesn't quite seem to work . I still see the floating text on the `top-left` corner

Comment: @Dwayne, never used Angular so I can't say for sure. If you inspect the element is there padding all around it?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the mat-label and add placeholder attribute in mat input.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <input type="text" matInput (keyup)="searchList($event.target.value)" placeholder="Find {{ this['groupType'] }} by Name" />
</mat-form-field>
```

Working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjhtdf

Answer (score 0):

```
<mat-form-field>
 <mat-label>Find {{ this['groupType'] }} by Name</mat-label>
        <input type="text" matInput (keyup)="searchList($event.target.value)" style="padding: 3px 10px; font-size: 20px;"/>
      </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

This link might be helpful for you

> [How to move placeholder to top on focus AND while typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942247/how-to-move-placeholder-to-top-on-focus-and-while-typing)